# How to get rid of extra field and values after grok transformation of input to json?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a logstash configuration that has as filter like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:inputs}"}
  }
  json {
    source => "inputs"
    target => "parsedJson"
    remove_field => ["inputs"]
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "serviceName" => "%{[parsedJson][serviceName]}"
      "thread_name" => "%{[parsedJson][thread_name]}"
    }
  }
}
```

It is working and I am getting field/variables names such as serviceName and thread_name in Elastic/Kibana. However, I am also getting some unwanted additional things, which I believe are due to the mutate:

[unwanted grok output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7KPK.png)

as you can see, there are additional "parsedJson.[field_name]" fields that are repeated. I've played with the json and mutate portion, but I can't seem to figure this out. Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Mutate filter have a `remove_field` function. You need to pass a list (always a list, even with only one element) of the fields you want to get rid of. If you need to remove a nested field, pass it's entire path, like `remove_field => ["[level_1][level_2][the_field_i_want_to_delete]"]`

Answer (score 0):

Use [remove_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field) in mutate filter.

```
mutate {
        remove_field => [ "[parsedJson][message]", "[parsedJson][serviceName]", "[parsedJson][thread_name]" ]
    }
```